How to create ontology classes dynamically in python
i try to transform a JSON file into a ontology class, but this JSON contain random data in form of dict so i have to create the class dynamically, i tried many of method but no one works, my last attempt looks like this  :
attributs_data = data.get("attributs", {}) # here i recover JSON data
if isinstance(attributs_data, dict):
    attributs = Attributs()
    document.has_attributs = attributs
    for key, value in attributs_data.items():
        prop_name = f"has_{key}"

        # Define the property dynamically within the ontology context
        with onto:
            # here i try every type of data to create de class  

            if isinstance(value, str):
                prop_cls = types.new_class(prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
                                           kwds={"domain": [Attributs], "range": [str]})


            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                nested_cls = types.new_class(key.replace(" ", "_").capitalize(), (Thing,))
                nested_instance = nested_cls()
                setattr(attributs, prop_name, nested_instance)
                for subkey, subvalue in value.items():
                    nested_prop_name = f"has_{subkey}"
                    with onto:
                        if isinstance(subvalue, str):
                            nested_prop_cls = types.new_class(nested_prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
                                                              kwds={"domain": [nested_cls], "range": [str]})
                        elif isinstance(subvalue, int):
                            nested_prop_cls = types.new_class(nested_prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
                                                              kwds={"domain": [nested_cls], "range": [int]})
                        elif isinstance(subvalue, float):
                            nested_prop_cls = types.new_class(nested_prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
                                                              kwds={"domain": [nested_cls], "range": [float]})
                        elif isinstance(subvalue, bool):
                            nested_prop_cls = types.new_class(nested_prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
                                                              kwds={"domain": [nested_cls], "range": [bool]})
                        setattr(nested_instance, nested_prop_name, subvalue)

and every time i got this error who says
  File "jsonToOwl.py", line 115, in <module>
    prop_cls = types.new_class(prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/types.py", line 74, in new_class
    return meta(name, resolved_bases, ns, **kwds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: EntityClass.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'domain'

i just know that the error trigger on the types.new_class function but didn't see any documentation about this.
if anyone got an idea i would marry him or her

Maybe you should not pass 'domain' as keyword argument to new_class?

(I didn't strictly mean "as keyword argument", but "as part of the kwds argument")

when i made this                 prop_cls = types.new_class(prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,),kwds={ [Attributs],  [str]})
the error is TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' about the part of kwrd

Then you have more errors which you need to fix. For example, trying to construct a set { [Attributs], [str] } which contains lists. Lists cannot be contained in sets.

it seems that doing this work for me
prop_cls = types.new_class(prop_name, (FunctionalProperty,))
prop_cls.domain = [Attributs]
prop_cls.range = [str]
attributs.prop_cls = value

Maybe you should add some @context, creating JSON-LD from your JSON, then process this JSON-LD as RDF using appropriate tools.
